# WCF client certification

Tags: wcf, client

I have a WCF service which uses basicHttpBinding. Now I want to secure my methods so that no one can create a proxy and use my method. I used WCF client certification from msdn. But cant move further. here is my web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:57246/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
           behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:57246/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
       binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
       contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />

      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>

          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

now what should pass call form the c sharp. I have a method in WCF named showGrid.

```
public DataSet showGrid()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Resources", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

and trying to call it like this on a button click

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();


 client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost");
        client.showGrid();
        GridView1.DataSource = client.showGrid();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Now one exception is throwing like this

Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'localhost'.

How to overcome this. Please help me. I also google for it. I am using windows 7 And is this a right way to secure my Method? Please guide me. Looking for this issue for many days.

Answer (score 1):

Just add client certificate like this

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = yourcert;
```

Edit:

```
        X509Certificate2 yourcert= null; 
        var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(findType, thumbprint, false);
        if (certCollection.Count>0)
            yourcert= certCollection[0];
        store.Close();
```

Comment: Dear Mx Kvt, thank you very much for your help. But did not get it. yourcert means? What should i write here. Please help me i am new user to WCF. And is it right approach what i am trying to do? I want one can see my methods.

Comment: Dear Mx Kvt, Thanks for your help. I have edit my issue. Please guide me how to solve this issue.